# How to share the ArrayList data in Android?

Tags: android, arraylist

How can I share the ArrayList Data in mail or message in Android?

Data I have stored in ArrayList String data, now I want to share it.

```
targetedShare.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, here I want to add the arraylist data);
targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase());
targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
```

Comment: please, describe how data, you want to share, should looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example here is a simple solution you could implement:

```
String[] lis= new String[5];
        for (int i=0;i< lis.length;i++)
        {
            lis[i]="Hi";
        }
        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0;i< lis.length;i++)
        {
            builder.append(lis[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
        String string=builder.toString();
        targetedShare.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, string);
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer its really helpful